# How to define date type in Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, odata, sencha-touch, sap-smp

I am working in a Sencha Touch app, backend is running with SAP, and is sending in the json this odata string format '20140811'(for instance) if I define in the model this type nothing happens..

```json
{
  name: "createdOn",
  type: "date",
  dateFormat: "DD-MM-Y"
}
```

How should I convert correctly Sap date format to Sencha type?

Comment: Got solution for this ?

Comment: No.. :-( I found an approach but I don´t like so much...

Comment: U have to convert string to dateformat before  setting data into the model. Is the only way to solve your problem like dateVar=new Date('2011-04-11') or you have change the format from server

Comment: I have posted the solution.. let me know your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was...

```
   {
    name: 'lastSurvey',
    type: 'auto',
    convert: function(date){
      var sNumber = date.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ''),
        iNumber = sNumber * 1, //trick seventeen
        oDate = new Date(iNumber);
      return Ext.Date.format(oDate, 'd-m-Y');
    }
  },
```

Opinions about this solution are welcome!